# Binomial AB Test - binomial test vs normal approximation

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution, ab-test, normal-approximation

I want to run an ab test on two groups of people

[image]

If I use the binomial test I get a p-value of 0.007355

```
# Get values set up
num_a, num_b = 550, 450
click_a, click_b = 48, 56
rate_a, rate_b = click_a / num_a, click_b / num_b

# Get 
from scipy import stats
p=stats.binom_test(x=click_b, # Successes
                 n=num_b, # bnumber of trials
                 p=rate_a, #hypthesized probablity of success
                 alternative='two-sided' #{‘two-sided’, ‘greater’, ‘less’},
                )
p
```

If I use the normal approximation, I get a p-value of 0.0294

```
from scipy.stats import norm

# Where does this come from? See the link above.
std_a = np.sqrt(rate_a * (1 - rate_a) / num_a)
std_b = np.sqrt(rate_b * (1 - rate_b) / num_b)


click_rate = np.linspace(0, 0.2, 200)
prob_a = norm(rate_a, std_a).pdf(click_rate)
prob_b = norm(rate_b, std_b).pdf(click_rate)


# The z-score is really all we need if we want a number
z_score = (rate_b - rate_a) / np.sqrt(std_a**2 + std_b**2)
print(f"z-score is {z_score:0.3f}, with p-value {norm().sf(z_score)}")
```

If I use an online testing calculator(https://abtestguide.com/calc/), I get 0.0294 as well.

Mann Whitney gives a different value as well of 0.05555

```
from scipy.stats import mannwhitneyu
a_dist = np.zeros(num_a)
a_dist[:click_a] = 1
b_dist = np.zeros(num_b)
b_dist[:click_b] = 1
stat, p_value = mannwhitneyu(a_dist, b_dist, alternative="two-sided")
print(f"Mann-Whitney U test for null hypothesis B <= A is {p_value}")
```

Why is the p-value from the binomial test so different than the one from the normal approximation and z test?  Which one should I use?

Comment: There are a few things in play: 1) Normal approximation of a binomial r.v. may not work well for small p, though given your sample size it is unlikely that is the main contributor of bias in Type I error rate. 2) In the binomial test you are assuming the email open rate is constant for control (effectively running a one-sample test), whereas in the t-test you take the email open rate for control as a random sample with some variance (effectively running a two-sample test). In a grossly simplified sense the t-statistic is subject to double the variance, resulting in a higher p-value.

Comment: 3) In the binomial test you have a two-sided alternate hypothesis, whereas in the t-test you created a p-value for a one-sided alternate hypothesis. All of which makes these two test at the form you present not comparable at all.

Comment: Thank you! this is so helpful!  Is there a test I could do that does not rely on normal approximation but that does let the email rate be not constant for control?

Comment: Or in other words, what would you do if your sample was small enough that you couldn't use the normal approximation (and is there a general size for "too small")?

Comment: [Fisher's exact test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test) may work for your case. It is the 2x2, exact version of the chi-squared goodness of fit test that works on binomial responses.

Comment: Apologies for my poor English in the previous comments - the comments were typed very hastily. I will do the clean up when I get the time later.